# Docker-compose host network_mode does not work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run container with host network mode and it does not work:

```
version: '2'
services:
  tests:
    container_name: my_container
    build: .
    network_mode: "host"
```

I got 'Connection refused' when do `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:7878`
(this is my server which is up and running locally)

Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac219

Update

```
docker ps



CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES d1e3ac55cfaa app_cont "/bin/sh -c 'sh -c..." 17 seconds ago Up 18 seconds my_container 


sudo netstat -plant


netstat: lant: unknown or uninstrumented protocol
```

Host OS: OSX 10.12

Comment: What is the output of `sudo netstat -plant` and `docker ps` after you up the compose using `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: > docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d1e3ac55cfaa        app_cont     "/bin/sh -c 'sh -c..."   17 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds                           my_container



>sudo netstat -plant
netstat: lant: unknown or uninstrumented protocol

Comment: which Host OS are you using? Also please edit question and then add logs, not in comments. It becomes hard to read

Comment: Pardon, I have updated question.

Comment: `network_mode: host` doesn't work on OSX. You need to map the port

Comment: Is this issue or feature?

Comment: It's networking limitation when it comes to docker for Mac